# Dynamically change Dojo multiselect values

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to add a multiselect widget to a form that is set with some values. And when the user clicks on a button, the values inside the multiselect widget changes.

When I do this the form crashes.

This is a sample code for the issue:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
    function test(){

        var msObj = dijit.byId('ms1');
        msObj.set('label', ['val1', 'val2']);

    }
    </script>

</head>
<body class="claro">

<h2>Multiselect Test</h2>
<h3>Click on test button to see new data loaded in the multiselect widget</h3>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action="" method="POST">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/TableContainer"
            data-dojo-props="cols:1">

            <select id="ms1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/MultiSelect"
                title="MultiSelect123:" name="multi_select">
                <option value="English 123">English 123</option>
                <option value="1234.56">1234.56</option>
            </select> 


        </div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="test()">test</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the crash is because on clicking the button the form gets submitted.
To avoid submitting the form we need to return false value in the button click function. i.e

```
<button onclick="test(); return false;">test</button>
```

Also the Multiselect Dojo widget is not associated with a data store/object. As per the documentation it is just a wrapper over the **SELECT** HTML element.
As a result you need to use the basic HTML/JS code to add and remove the **OPTIONS** for the widget.

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/11xvwcxo/1/) for a working example.